# Use of simple delegate

Tags: c#

a simple delegate just point a function and later when we call delegate then mapped function is invoke.

i hardly use delegate.so i just want to know why one should use simple delegate. here i am giving a sample code of use delegate.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

delegate void DisplayMessage(string message);

public class TestCustomDelegate
{
   public static void Main()
   {
        DisplayMessage messageTarget;

        if (Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Length > 1)
            messageTarget = ShowWindowsMessage;
        else
            messageTarget = Console.WriteLine;

        messageTarget("Hello, World!");
   }

   private static void ShowWindowsMessage(string message)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(message);
   }
}
```

in the above example a delegate just point a function and when we invoke delegate then a function is called which is mapped. here we can directly call the function then why one should use delegate. please explain with good sample which describe the advantage of delegate. in my above program we can directly call ShowWindowsMessage function and there delegate is not required.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic example:

When using Sort() you can pass a delegate to a comparison function.
In this case you want to Sort a collection, but don't yet know how it will be sorted (of course there is a default) but you want to be able to just use a function that will be decided upon in a future date.

So using a delegate to pass a function as an argument will be useful.

[List.Sort Method (Comparison)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx)

Comment: This is commonly referred to as the Strategy Pattern - a perfect example of using delegates :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you familiarize yourself with [first-class functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function), and [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29). And after that, how [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx) are used in C#

Also, you can access program arguments by adding it to the main method.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DisplayMessage messageTarget;

    if (args.Length > 1)
        messageTarget = ShowWindowsMessage;

    // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

For example I have a code like this:

```
public static class MemberEvaluator
{
   public static TResult With<TInput, TResult>(this TInput o, 
                                               Func<TInput, TResult> evaluator)
        where TResult : class
        where TInput : class
    {
        if (o == null) return null;
        return evaluator(o);
    }
}
```

In the case `TInput o` is null, it doesn't throw an exception, it just returns null, this is helpful to skip null checking, I can do two line of code every where, but when you work on project with lot of need of this, It's better to have a simple function to do it, you can call it by `x.With(q=>q.Z)` to get `x.q.Z` without null checking, as you can see `q=>q.Z` is a simple delegate with very good usage. in fact it's `Func<TInput, TResult> evaluator` as input of my checker function.

**Edit:** This is an extension class with one extension method, which evaluates members of object. you can find full code [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/maybemonads.aspx).

Comment: thanks for your answer but your code is not full code to understand what you were trying to say and also very tough to understand. please give the full code.thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your very simple example there is clearly no need for delegates as you've realised

The MSDN contains lots of information about the .NET framework. A quick search around there can quite often come up with an answer to most .net questions.

I've searched for you and found this..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=VS.100%29.aspx